# manipulate variables in short circuited zsh if statement with parentheses

Tags: zsh

In a zsh completion function I'm confronted with the following if statement

```bsh
if _cache_invalid my_data || ( [[ ${+_my_array_var} -eq 0 ]] && ! _retrieve_cache my_data ) ; then ...
```

the idea is: if the cache is invalid, enter the if block. otherwise check if `_my_array_var` is set, if not try to retrieve it from the cache. If `_my_array_var` is not set and if cache retrieval fails, also enter the if block. As far as my debugging goes, the logic of the if statement is fine, however the second half of the if statement fails to populate the `_my_array_var` variable if it is successfully retrieved from the cache.

In a shorter test I figured out that I blame the parentheses

```bsh
echo ${+_my_array_var}
if [[ ${+_my_array_var} -eq 0 ]] && !_retrieve_cache my_data; then echo "entered" ; fi
echo ${+_my_array_var}
```

this echoes `0` then `1` (i.e. `_my_array_var` was unset, cache retrieval worked and afterwards `_my_array_var` is set. When I add parentheses

```bsh
echo ${+_my_array_var}
if ( [[ ${+_my_array_var} -eq 0 ]] && !_retrieve_cache my_data ); then echo "entered" ; fi
echo ${+_my_array_var}
```

this echos `0` twice, i.e. the if block is still not entered, but the population of `_my_array_var` didn't "leave" the if test.

So it appears to me that in the original code, I should get rid of the parentheses, but I want to do so without changing the hierarchy of the expressions or the behavior of short circuiting.

How do I set the `||` and `&&` associativity without using parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis in `zsh` like in all Bourne-like shells is to run a subshell.

To group commands, use the `{ ...; }` *command group* instead:

```
if
  _cache_invalid my_data || {
    (( $+_my_array_var == 0 )) &&
      ! _retrieve_cache my_data
  }
then ...
```

Or:

```
if
  _cache_invalid my_data || ! {
    (($+_my_array_var )) || _retrieve_cache my_data
  }
then ...
```

See [`info zsh subshell`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-subshell) for details:

> `( LIST )`
>        Execute LIST in a subshell.  Traps set by the trap builtin are
>        reset to their default values while executing LIST.
>
> `{ LIST }`
>        Execute LIST.